# php preg_replace help Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses

Tags: php, joomla, preg-replace, vertex

Not sure if im just being stupid or something but here goes i work for Shape5.com and i made there Vertex Framework the problem is Joomla keeps updating and this has popped up in our forums several times the error is Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 67

this is our code

```
<?php
$script = "Hello window.addEvent('domready', function(){ new Fx.Accordion($$('div#template-sliders-116.pane-sliders > .panel > h3.pane-toggler'), $$('div#template-sliders-116.pane-sliders > .panel > div.pane-slider'), {onActive: function(toggler, i) {toggler.addClass('pane-toggler-down');toggler.removeClass('pane-toggler');i.addClass('pane-down');i.removeClass('pane-hide');Cookie.write('jpanesliders_template-sliders-116',$$('div#template-sliders-116.pane-sliders > .panel > h3').indexOf(toggler));},onBackground: function(toggler, i) {toggler.addClass('pane-toggler');toggler.removeClass('pane-toggler-down');i.addClass('pane-hide');i.removeClass('pane-down');if($$('div#template-sliders-116.pane-sliders > .panel > h3').length==$$('div#template-sliders-116.pane-sliders > .panel > h3.pane-toggler').length) Cookie.write('jpanesliders_template-sliders-116',-1);},duration: 300,opacity: false,alwaysHide: true}); });";
$script = preg_replace("/window.addEvent('domready', function(){ new Fx.Accordion(.*?)}); });/", '', $script);
echo $script;
?>
```

the problem is the Fx.Accordion is forever changing depending on what template they use and this is really bugging me now sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't ive tried escaping some all and none but still get the error the code above will reproduce the error exactly as we see it if anyone could help that be smashing.

Offset 67 is the last ) and yes ive tried escaping it removing it u name it ive tried :D

I bet its something simple lol

Thanks Dave

Comment: You need to escape the [meta character](http://php.net/regexp.reference.meta) if they should be interpreted as literal characters.

Comment: You can replace all that code with `echo "Hello ";`

Comment: I think this is probably overcomplicating something that could be done in a different way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parentheses are special characters in PCRE for capture grouping, which require escaping via backslash, as do the `{}` which would otherwise be range specifiers, and the dot `.`.

```
$script = preg_replace("/window\.addEvent\('domready', function\(\)\{ new Fx.Accordion\(.*?\)\}\); \}\);/", '', $script);
```

I think I have that all properly escaped.  I assume the `(.*?)` was not intended to be a capture group.  The `?` is actually unnecessary in there because `.*` implies zero or more of any character.

```
$script = preg_replace("/window\.addEvent\('domready', function\(\)\{ new Fx.Accordion(.*?)\}\); \}\);/", '', $script);
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------Don't escape ^^^^^
```

Update: If the `(.*?)` was intended as a nongreedy match group, then don't escape it.

Comment: @Gumbo Yep, and I'm still scanning for other stuff I missed.

Comment: ive just ran the code and it does nothing im affraid :D what i want to leave is just Hello

Comment: @BigDave see edit above.  Don't escape the `(.*?)` and it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your amazing help it was this in the end `code`$script = preg_replace("/window\.addEvent\('domready', function\(\)\{ new Fx.Accordion(.*)\}\); \}\);/", '', $script);